# Swift UITableView multiline cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add multiple lines to a tableView cell but am not having much success. I have seen related posts suggesting I use :

```
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

but when I used that I get an error saying: Use of unresolved identifier 'UILineBreakModeWordWrap'. So im not sure why it is throwing that error. Also, how would one go about actually adding a new line? Would it be something like this:

```
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Location Name"
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Locations Address: 123 main street \nNew Line here \nNew Line here"
```

I am running XCode 6 and developing for iOS 8.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much of a Swift guy but shouldn't it be:

```
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
```

or something like that.

`UILabel lineBreakMode` is of type `NSLineBreakMode` and the Swift value you want is `ByWordWrapping`.

The value `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is the old Objective-C value that was deprecated in iOS 6.

Comment: sorry fir delayed response, but ive tried that with no luck.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Sadly it does nothing, the size does not increase. This is very bizzare

Comment: Your question was about the error. Is that fixed? If so, close this question and ask a new one about the new problem.